# Try-catch-finally from java to c++

Tags: java, c++, exception, switch-statement, try-catch-finally

I want to translate the java exception handling in c ++, without using RAII.

The problem mainly concerns the finally block.

I found a paper which use the following approach:

"One difficulty is that the finally clause must be executed before every exit from the try block. There are a surprising number of potential exits from a general try block: a normal exit, throwing an exception, a return
statement, a break statement, a continue statement, or failing to catch an exception. The finally clause must be executed before each of these (if they are used in the try block or a catch block). For example, the following Java code shows most of the ways to exit from a try block:

```
try {
  switch (x) {
    case 0: continue next;
    case 1: break out;
    case 2: throw new TException();
    case 3: return(0);
  }
} catch (Error e) {
    throw(e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("finally");
}
```

Our solution then is to simply duplicate the text of the finally block in all places where it must be executued. If the finally block is significant in size, this might suggest that the Java programmer might want to make it a method, in order to minimize the code repetition in C++.

The following C++ code shows how the finally block must be replicated for all the exits from a try block:"

```
  try
   {
     switch(x)
     {
     case 0:
     /* finally clause, continue from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     goto next;
     case 1:
     /* finally clause, break from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     goto out;
     case 2:
     /* finally clause, throw exception from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     throw(new TException());
     case 3:
     /* finally clause, return from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     return(0);
     }
   }
   catch(java_lang_Error *e)
   {
     /* finally clause, caught exception from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     throw(e);
   }
   catch(...)
   {
     /* finally clause, uncaught exception from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
     throw;
   }
     /* finally clause, normal exit from try block */
     java_lang_System::out->println(_j_toString("finally"));
```

I do not understand how to use it in a real generic program example. What is the variable x in the switch and how should I use it?

Comment: "I want to speak English, without using the present simple tense."

Comment: _"...without using RAII"_ why?  Java needs finally because it does __not__ have RAII.

Comment: _I want to translate the java exception handling in c ++, without using RAII_ Problem starts here.

Comment: _goto next;_ are you serious?

Answer (score 5):

The [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) is a library that supports the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). The guidelines recommend using [gsl::finally](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util) for this:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_util>

int main()
{
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(nullptr)));

    auto cleanup = gsl::finally([]{
        std::cout << "FINALLY it is my turn." << '\n';
    });

    try
    {
        if(std::rand() % 2)
            throw std::runtime_error("Woopsie 1");

        if(std::rand() % 2)
            throw std::logic_error("Woopsie 2");

        std::cout << "No woopsies on me" << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::logic_error const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

But you really should move to a `RAII` design for new classes. That would obviate the need to use a "finally" object.

**Note:** Please get your random numbers from `#include <random>` in real life.

Comment: But that's RAII ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller Hah! I was trying to keep that a secret! Well, it's kind of an *external RAII object* that cleans up after all  your non RAII objects. The best solution is to make all your objects `RAII`.

Comment: A designated RAII class is much better, I agree 100%. Though I feel that if [p0577r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0577r0.pdf) is accepted into C++2a, we'll be seeing much more use of `gsl::finally`.

Answer (score 1):

It is just sample code. The point made, is that the java finally block actually is inserted at multiple points. The shown code is just a sample, listing `break`, `continue`, `return` and `throw` that need to copy the code of the finally block - as *final* code.

For instance:

```
try {
    ...
    return ...;
    ...
} finally {
    A;
}
```

would become

```
try {
    ...
    { A; }
    return ...;
    ...
    { A; }
} catch (java_lang_Error *e) {
    A;
    throw e; // If the catch was not there originally
}
```

Actually this is what happens in java bytecode.

So all code leaving the java try-finally needs to copy the code of the finally block.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your transformation. If an exception is thrown before the first `{ A; }` it won't execute the second inserted block. So it's not really semantically equivalent

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, I forgot to add the `catch` as control flow element. Indeed in the original code there would not need to be a catch. The answer from Galik treats possible exceptions better; `java_lang_Error` does not make sense. However I wanted to tell, that evidently the code was not seen by the OP as the sample code it is.